# How to get a RESTful response with sub-resource represented as uri using FOS Rest Bundle and Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I am using Symfony2 with Doctrine and FOS Rest Bundle (which uses JMS serializer).
There are two **entities** *Father* and *Child*:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Father
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Father {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     **/
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;
}
```

and

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Child
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Child {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     **/
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Father")
     **/
    private $father;
}
```

There are **routes**:

```
acme_test_child_all:
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeCoreBundle:Test:childAll }
    path:   /child/
acme_test_father_get:
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeCoreBundle:Test:fatherGet }
    path:   /father/{id}
```

And finally there is a **controller** with actions for these routes:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\CoreBundle\Controller;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class TestController extends Controller {
    /**
     * @Rest\View()
     */
    public function childAllAction() {
        $children = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AcmeCoreBundle:Child')
            ->findAll();

        return $children;
    }

    /**
     * @Rest\View()
     */
    public function fatherGetAction($id) {
        $father = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AcmeCoreBundle:Child')
            ->findById($id);

        return $father;
    }
}
```

When I call **GET /child/** I get the expected response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "father": {
            "id":1,
            "name":"Father"
        }
    }
]
```

Instead of nested response I would like to get an **uri** of Father resource, i.e.:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "father": "/father/1"
    }
]
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with one of Hateoas bundles for example: [BazingaHateoasBundle](https://github.com/willdurand/Hateoas) or [FSCHateoasBundle](https://github.com/TheFootballSocialClub/FSCHateoasBundle). You can probably search more using http://knpbundles.com

Comment: The FSCHateoasBundle is about to be deprecated in favor of the [Hateoas](https://github.com/willdurand/Hateoas) lib, and its bundle (BazingaHateoasBundle).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "father" `virtualProperty` that uses your custom logic to return the value for "father" field.

See:
[JMSSerializer YAML config reference](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/yml_reference)